# How to prevent a signup when user already exists Sinatra

Tags: ruby, forms, sinatra, ruby-datamapper

I am trying to create a simple sign up form using Sinatra and data mapper that signs up a user only if one already does not exist. The problem seems to be that no user is created using the code below

```
def signup(username, password, email)
  @user = User.new(username: username, password: password, email: email)
  @user.save if not User.all(:username => username, :email => email)
end
```

I have been looking but for the life of me cannot figure it out. Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@user = User.first_or_create(:username => username, :email => email)
```

Yo can use warden with sinatra, and make your life easier. Check demo [here](https://gist.github.com/lukesutton/107966).

Note: favor unless over if for negative conditions

Comment: Thanks I'll use that.

Answer (score 0):

I making a gem [Vxod](https://github.com/SergXIIIth/vxod) for "Social and password authorization solution" for any Rake framework, any ORM.

Currently [Vxod](https://github.com/SergXIIIth/vxod) tested on Sinatra and Mongoid.